# NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces causes AppDomain.UnhandledException to stop firing on Windows XP Embedded

Tags: .net, exception, mobile, windows-xp, embedded

I have an application that targets desktop OSes (XP, Vista, Win7) as well as mobile devices running Windows XP Embedded. All platforms are running the full .Net Framework, *not* the Compact Framework. The app uses the `AppDomain.UnhandledException` event to detect and log any fatal application errors. Nothing unusual there, and it works perfectly -- at least on the desktop OSes.

At another place in the application, there is a piece of code that calls the `NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces` method to get a list of NICs on the machine. On Windows XP Embedded -- but not the desktop OSes -- once this method has been called, the `AppDomain.UnhandledException` event no longer fires when unhandled exceptions occur. Instead, the app just crashes, without even displaying the standard .Net crash dialog.

Is this a known bug, or am I doing something wrong? Does anybody know a workaround for this?

Here is a sample application that reproduces the problem. This example is written in WinForms, but the same problem occurs in WPF as well.

```
using System;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BugDemo
{
    public class BugDemoForm : Form
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// This is the entry point of the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
            Application.Run(new BugDemoForm());
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets up a simple form with two buttons for reproducing the bug.
        /// </summary>
        public BugDemoForm()
        {
            Padding = new Padding(15);
            Width = 400;
            int halfHeight = (ClientRectangle.Height / 2) - Padding.Vertical;

            Button exceptionButton = new Button();
            exceptionButton.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
            exceptionButton.Height = halfHeight;
            exceptionButton.Text = "Test the AppDomain.UnhandledException method";
            exceptionButton.Click += exceptionButton_Click;
            Controls.Add(exceptionButton);

            Button networkInterfacesButton = new Button();
            networkInterfacesButton.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
            networkInterfacesButton.Height = halfHeight;
            networkInterfacesButton.Text = "Call the NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces method";
            networkInterfacesButton.Click += networkInterfacesButton_Click;
            Controls.Add(networkInterfacesButton);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Throws an exception on a background thread. 
        /// This will cause the <see cref="AppDomain.UnhandledException"/> event to fire.
        /// </summary>
        private static void exceptionButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
                delegate(object state)
                {
                    throw new ApplicationException();
                });
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Calls the <see cref="NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces"/> method.
        /// Once this method is called, the <see cref="AppDomain.UnhandledException"/> event
        /// will no longer fire.
        /// </summary>
        private static void networkInterfacesButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NetworkInterface[] nics = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
            MessageBox.Show("There are " + nics.Length + " network interfaces on this machine.\n\n"
                + "Now that the NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces method has been called, "
                + "the AppDomain.UnhandledException event will no longer fire when running on "
                + "Windows XP Embedded.");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Fires whenever an unhandled exception occurs on a background thread.
        /// However, once the <see cref="NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces"/> method has been
        /// called, this event no longer fires.
        /// </summary>
        private static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The AppDomain.UnhandledException event fired successfully.\n"
                + "The app will now crash, as expected.");
        }
    }
}
```